# Explicit formula for Savitzky-Golay matrix

Tags: math

Does anyone have an explicit formula to calculate the entries of the Savitzky-Golay Matrix. i.e. a direct expression that only depends on the radii of the tensor in its various dimensions, the polynomial regression orders and the derivative orders.

There are examples for finite sets of data-points but i can't seem to find an explicit formula.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs to [Mathematics](https://math.stackexchange.com)

Comment: Would this help: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/9077 ?

Comment: I see [the Wikipedia article about Savitzky-Golay filtering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Savitzky%E2%80%93Golay_filter) has some formulas. May I ask what's missing from your point of view? I don't understand what more you are looking for.

Comment: @RobertDodier maybe I'm just not seeing it on the Wikipedia page, What i am searching for is a formula that tells me as a function of the dimensionality of the Savitzky-Golay matrix i want to calculate, how each entry is calculated as a function of the radius of that matrix as well as the polynomial and derivative orders. I don't find such an expression on the Wikipedia page. But maybe I'm looking at it wrongly..?

Comment: By radius of the matrix, do you mean the magnitude of the largest eigenvalue? or what?

Comment: @RobertDodier I'm looking for a function of the form SGi1i2,...(r1,...,rn,k1,...,kn,d1,...,dn) where i1, i2, ... in is the index of the matrix element, r1,... rn are the radii in each dimension, k1,...,k2 are the polynomial orders in each dimension and d1,...dn are the derivative orders in each dimension.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Unfortunately I must admit I don't have anything helpful to add at this point.